# Inno Setup: Iterate through array of type Variant (from OleObject)

Tags: inno-setup, ole, variant, pascalscript, iis-metabase

I'm trying to read and write to the IIS 6 metabase using Inno Setup.
I can't figure out how to access arrays though.

```pascal
IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
Compr := IIS.GetObject('IIsCompressionScheme', 'localhost/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/deflate');
Arr := Compr.HcScriptFileExtensions;
{ ... [code to iterate and add items] here ... }
Compr.SetInfo();
```

The metabase editor calls the object type I'm trying to access a "multi-string".

`VarType(Arr)` yields 0x200C as type (see http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_vartype.htm)

How can I work with such types of variables? Delphi supports something like

```pascal
for I := VarArrayLowBound(Arr, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(Arr, 1) do
```

but Inno Setup doesn't. Or do I have to access the array completely via some OLE/COM-functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the `Variant` to `array of string`, read and write the array and then cast back:

```pascal
var
  VariantArray: Variant;
  Count: Integer;
  ArrayOfStrings: array of string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  { ... }
  VariantArray := Compr.HcScriptFileExtensions;

  { Cast to array }
  ArrayOfStrings := VariantArray;

  { Read the array }
  Count := GetArrayLength(ArrayOfStrings);
  Log(Format('Count = %d', [Count]));

  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    Log(Format('%d: %s', [I, ArrayOfStrings[I]]));
  end;

  { Modify the array (append element) }
  SetArrayLength(ArrayOfStrings, Count + 1);
  ArrayOfStrings[Count] := 'new string';

  { Cast back to the variant }
  VariantArray := ArrayOfStrings;
  ...
end;
```

Works in Unicode version of Inno Setup only. Probably because the *[Unicode Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode) is compiled with Delphi 2009 instead of Delphi 2 and 3*, which likely has better Variant support. See also [Upgrading from Ansi to Unicode version of Inno Setup (any disadvantages)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848).

Answer (score -1):

Inno does not provide full Delphi support, as far as I remember the scripting language is based on Free Pascal.

Try the following:

```
 for I := 0 to  GetArrayLength(myArray) - 1 do
  begin
     //stuff
  end;
```

Comment: You cannot call `GetArrayLength` on `Variant`. You get runtime error *"Could not call proc."*

Comment: My bad, I assumed array of string.