# Is there a way to read the system's information in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to read the system's information in Inno Setup, during installation (just at the welcome wizard page)?

By this I mean:

- RAM
- OS
- CPU
- user
- IP
- MAC adress.

It would be a good thing to know. I would like to put this information in say a text document that I would save on my computer. I cannot seem to find material on this online at all, and was hoping if anyone had experience with this, could help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many different ways to retrieve all these information.

But one universal way to retrieve all of them is a [WMI query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/querying-wmi).

WMI classes that will interest you are:

- [`Win32_ComputerSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem)
- [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem)
- [`Win32_Processor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor)
- [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration)

```pascal
function WbemQuery(WbemServices: Variant; Query: string): Variant;
var
  WbemObjectSet: Variant;
begin
  Result := Null;
  WbemObjectSet := WbemServices.ExecQuery(Query);
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin
    Result := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(0);
  end;
end;

procedure CollectInformation;
var
  Query: string;
  WbemLocator, WbemServices: Variant;
  ComputerSystem, OperatingSystem, Processor: Variant;
  NetworkAdapters, NetworkAdapter: Variant;
  IPAddresses: array of string;
  I, I2: Integer;
begin
  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WbemServices := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('.', 'root\CIMV2');
  
  Query := 'SELECT TotalPhysicalMemory, UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem';
  ComputerSystem := WbemQuery(WbemServices, Query);
  if not VarIsNull(ComputerSystem) then
  begin
    Log(Format('TotalPhysicalMemory=%s', [ComputerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory]));
    Log(Format('UserName=%s', [ComputerSystem.UserName]));
  end;
  
  Query := 'SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem';
  OperatingSystem := WbemQuery(WbemServices, Query);
  if not VarIsNull(OperatingSystem) then
  begin
    Log(Format('OperatingSystem=%s', [OperatingSystem.Caption]));
  end;

  Query := 'SELECT Name FROM Win32_Processor';
  Processor := WbemQuery(WbemServices, Query);
  if not VarIsNull(Processor) then
  begin
    Log(Format('Processor=%s', [Processor.Name]));
  end;
  
  Query :=
    'SELECT IPEnabled, IPAddress, MACAddress ' +
    'FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration';
  NetworkAdapters := WbemServices.ExecQuery(Query);
  if not VarIsNull(NetworkAdapters) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to NetworkAdapters.Count - 1 do
    begin
      NetworkAdapter := NetworkAdapters.ItemIndex(I);
      if (not VarIsNull(NetworkAdapter.MACAddress)) and
         NetworkAdapter.IPEnabled then
      begin
        Log(Format('Adapter %d MAC=%s', [I, NetworkAdapter.MACAddress]));
        if not VarIsNull(NetworkAdapter.IPAddress) then
        begin
          IPAddresses := NetworkAdapter.IPAddress;
          for I2 := 0 to GetArrayLength(IPAddresses) - 1 do
          begin
            Log(Format('Adapter %d IP %d=%s', [I, I2, IPAddresses[I2]]));
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

*The code requires Unicode version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup 6) for a [better `Variant` support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34317882/850848).*

*The [`SWbemObjectSet.ItemIndex` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemobjectset-itemindex) used with `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` is not available on Windows XP an older. See [Iterate SWbemObjectSet in Windows XP and Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43222471/850848)*.

---

It will get you information like:

```
TotalPhysicalMemory=12835962880
UserName=domain\martin
OperatingSystem=Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Processor=Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz
Adapter 1 MAC=11:51:67:D0:10:21
Adapter 1 IP 0=192.168.78.2
Adapter 1 IP 1=ef08::8da9:601e:3f8a:da00
Adapter 2 MAC=80:06:E6:10:F7:B9
Adapter 2 IP 0=192.168.1.3
```

---

To see all available information in involved classes, run this on command-line:

```
wmic computersystem get * /format:value
wmic os get * /format:value
wmic cpu get * /format:value
wmic nicconfig get * /format:value
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot man. I will asked questions here if any come up. This is great.