# Inno Setup: Inherited OLE-Object properties not accessible?

Tags: wmi, inno-setup, ole, pascalscript, wbem

I followed this [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762683/) accepted answer to query the machines network adapters. It finally worked but I still face a problem reading the values of these properties:

- Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Caption
- Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Description

Every time the code reaches this line where `networkAdapter.Caption` is called a runtime error is produced saying:

> Runtime error (at 60:8952): Unknown method.

This is my code, adopted from the above mentioned Stack Overflow question:

```pascal
Log('Querying WMI for network adapter data...');
query := 'SELECT IPEnabled, IPAddress, MACAddress, InterfaceIndex FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration';
networkAdapters := wbemServices.ExecQuery(query);
if not VarIsNull(networkAdapters) then
begin
  for i := 0 to networkAdapters.Count - 1 do
  begin
    networkAdapter := networkAdapters.ItemIndex(i);

    if (not VarIsNull(networkAdapter.MACAddress)) and networkAdapter.IPEnabled and (not VarIsNull(networkAdapter.IPAddress)) then
    begin
      SetArrayLength(sysInfo.networkAdapters, GetArrayLength(sysInfo.networkAdapters) + 1);

      nicRec := sysInfo.networkAdapters[adapterIndex];

      { Adapter name }
      nicRec.name := defaultIfNull(networkAdapter.Caption, Format('Adapter %d', [i]));
      Log(Format('    NIC[%d] name........: %s', [adapterIndex, nicRec.name]));
      { Adapter index }
      nicRec.index := defaultIfNull(networkAdapter.InterfaceIndex, adapterIndex);
      Log(Format('    NIC[%d] index.......: %d', [adapterIndex, nicRec.index]));
      { Adapter MAC address }
      nicRec.macAddress := defaultIfNull(networkAdapter.MACAddress, '');
      Log(Format('    NIC[%d] MAC address.: %s', [adapterIndex, nicRec.macAddress]));
      { Adapter ip address(es) }
      nicRec.ipAddresses := TStringList.Create;
      if not VarIsNull(networkAdapter.IPAddress) then
      begin
        ips := networkAdapter.IPAddress;
        for j := 0 to GetArrayLength(ips) - 1 do
        begin
          nicRec.ipAddresses.Add(ips[j]);
          Log(Format('    NIC[%d] IPv4 address: %s', [adapterIndex, nicRec.ipAddresses.Strings[j]]));          
        end;
      end;

      adapterIndex := adapterIndex + 1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

After some reading in the Microsoft docs, I came across the description of these properties. It states, that the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class extends the `CIM_Setting` class. The properties `Caption` and `Description` are defined there. Is this an issue with the Inno Setup compiler (I am using the latest 6.0.2) or do I have to apply some sort of cast to may variant variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that inherited properties are accessible. Actually Inno Setup does not even care what class is that. It uses [late binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding). Property name resolution is delegated to the class itself.

But you are not working with `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`. [`IWbemServices.ExecQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nf-wbemcli-iwbemservices-execquery) returns [`IEnumWbemClassObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nn-wbemcli-ienumwbemclassobject), which in turn enumerates [`IWbemClassObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nn-wbemcli-iwbemclassobject). And that contains results of **your query**. Your query does not ask for `Caption` and `Description` properties, so the result set naturally does not contain them.

Add the properties to the query:

```pascal
Query := 'SELECT IPEnabled, IPAddress, MACAddress, InterfaceIndex, Caption, Description FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration';
```

Comment: Man how damn stupid. Thank you. I did not even waste a second to think about the query myself.