# Pascal scripting: How do i find the manufacturer details of my server?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

So I have an inno setup script and using that it want to check if the the server the installation is happening on is a HP server ***ie:- the manufacturer of the server is HP***. Is there anyway to do that, i'm new to pascal scripting so any tips on how to solve this problem?

If more information is necessary please let me know so I can edit it in later.

Comment: Query `Manufacturer` property of the `Win32_ComputerSystem` class. How to query WMI you will certainly find over here.

Comment: For querying `Win32_ComputerSystem`, see [Is there a way to read the system's information in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40762683/850848).