# List all physical printers using WMI query in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, wmi-query, pascalscript

I'm trying to get the list of physical printer's name, that are connected to Windows, based on an answer from [Query available RAM in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035181/query-available-ram-in-inno-setup).

But just get: "Send To OneNote 16".

Here is my query:

```pascal
Query := 'SELECT Name FROM Win32_Printer';
Printer := WbemQuery(WbemServices, Query);
if not VarIsNull(Printer) then
begin
  Log(Format('Printers=%s', [Printer.Name]));
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate the result set:

```pascal
var
  Query: string;
  WbemLocator, WbemServices, WbemObjectSet: Variant;
  Printer: Variant;
  I: Integer;
begin
  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WbemServices := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('.', 'root\CIMV2');
  Query := 'SELECT Name FROM Win32_Printer';
  WbemObjectSet := WbemServices.ExecQuery(Query);
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to WbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Printer := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I);
      if not VarIsNull(Printer) then
      begin
        Log(Printer.Name);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

*The code requires Unicode version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup 6) for a [better `Variant` support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34317882/850848).*

---

Actually, you can see this code in the same question, where you took the `WbemQuery` from:
[Is there a way to read the system's information in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40762683/850848)

Note how the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` is iterated there.