# Correct way to add items to a list box in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, wmi-query, pascalscript

I got a code from [List all physical printers using WMI query in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167016/list-all-physical-printers-using-wmi-query-in-inno-setup) and I want to add the results to a list box. I have tried to do it before asking, but I just can't add all items. This is an my code:

```pascal
var
  Query, AllPrinters: string;
  WbemLocator, WbemServices, WbemObjectSet: Variant;
  Printer: Variant;
  I: Integer;
begin
  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WbemServices := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('.', 'root\CIMV2');
  Query := 'SELECT Name FROM Win32_Printer';
  WbemObjectSet := WbemServices.ExecQuery(Query);
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to WbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Printer := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I);
      if not VarIsNull(Printer) then
      begin
        Log(Printer.Name);
        AllPrinters := Printer.Name;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Then on a custom page do this:

```pascal
ListBoxPrinters.Items.Add(AllPrinters);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the items (printers) to the list box the same way, the original code adds them to the log: in the loop!

```pascal
for I := 0 to WbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do
begin
  Printer := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I);
  if not VarIsNull(Printer) then
  begin
    ListBoxPrinters.Items.Add(Printer.Name);
  end;
end;
```

Of course, you have to create the custom page with the `ListBoxPrinters` before iterating the printers.

---

If you cannot run the query after creating the page for whatever reason, you can store a printer list into `TStringList`.

```pascal
var
  Printers: TStringList;
```

```pascal
Printers := TStringList.Create;

for I := 0 to WbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do
begin
  Printer := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I);
  if not VarIsNull(Printer) then
  begin
    Printers.Add(Printer.Name);
  end;
end;
```

And once you have the list box ready, you just copy the list over to the box:

```pascal
ListBoxPrinters.Items.Assign(Printers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite always with the next `AllPrinters := Printer.Name;` the previous value !

simple build the `AllPrinters` string like that

```
....
AllPrinters := '';
....
for I := 0 to WbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Printer := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I);
      if not VarIsNull(Printer) then
      begin
        Log(Printer.Name);
        AllPrinters := AllPrinters + Printer.Name + #13#10;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

and

```
ListBoxPrinters.Items.Text := AllPrinters;
```